# Can't sign up users and see their data in firebase. Including authentication and storage. Using three view controllers to do this task

Tags: swift, firebase

```
    import UIKit
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseAuth
import Firebase


class RegisterationController: UIViewController {
    
    
    //MARK:- Properties
    
    private var viewModel = RegisterationViewModel()
    
    private var profileImage: UIImage?
    private let plushButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "plus_photo"), for: .normal)
        button.tintColor = .white
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleProfilePhotoSelected), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
    private let emailTextField: customTextField = {
        let tf = customTextField(placeholder: "Email")
        tf.keyboardType = .emailAddress
        return tf
    }()
    
    private let passwordTextField: customTextField = {
        let tf = customTextField(placeholder: "Password")
        tf.isSecureTextEntry = true
        return tf
    }()
    
    private let fullnameTextField = customTextField(placeholder: "Full Name")
    private let usernameTextField = customTextField(placeholder: "Username")
    //private let phonenumberTextField = customTextField(placeholder: "Phone Number")
    
    private let signUpButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("Sign Up", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.2271653199, blue: 0.6822013588, alpha: 1)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        button.setHeight(50)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        button.isEnabled = true
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSignUp), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
    
    private let alreadyHaveAccountButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.attributedTitle(firstPart: "Already have an account?", secondPart: "Log in")
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleShowLogin), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
        
    }()
    
    //MARK:- Lifecycle
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    configureUI()
    configureNotificationsObservers()
    
    
    }
    
    //MARK: - Actions
    @objc func handleSignUp() {
        
        guard let email = emailTextField.text?.lowercased() else { return }
        guard let password = passwordTextField.text else { return }
        guard let username = usernameTextField.text?.lowercased() else { return }
        guard let fullName = fullnameTextField.text else { return }
        //guard let phoneNumber = phonenumberTextField.text else { return }
        guard let profileImage = self.profileImage else { return }
        
        let credentials = AuthCredentials(email: email, username: username, password: password, profileImage: profileImage, fullname: fullName)
        AuthService.registerUser(withCredentials: credentials) { error in
            if let error = error {
                print("DEBUG: Failed to register user \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            print("DEBUG: Succesfully registered in firestore")
        }
        
    }
    @objc func handleShowLogin() {
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
    
    @objc func textDidChange(sender: UITextField) {
        if sender == emailTextField {
            viewModel.email = sender.text
        } else if sender == passwordTextField{
            viewModel.password = sender.text
        } else if sender == fullnameTextField {
            viewModel.username = sender.text
        }
//         else if sender == phonenumberTextField {
//            viewModel.phonenumber = sender.text
//        }
        updateForm()
    }
    
    @objc func handleProfilePhotoSelected() {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.allowsEditing = true
        present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    //MARK:- Helpers
    
    func configureUI() {
        configureGradientLayer()
        
        view.addSubview(plushButton)
        plushButton.centerX(inView: view)
        plushButton.setDimensions(height: 140, width: 140)
        plushButton.anchor(top: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, paddingTop: 32)
        
        let stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [emailTextField, passwordTextField, fullnameTextField, usernameTextField, signUpButton])
        stack.axis = .vertical
        stack.spacing = 20

        view.addSubview(stack)
        
        stack.anchor(top: plushButton.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 32, paddingLeft: 32, paddingRight: 32)
        view.addSubview(alreadyHaveAccountButton)
        alreadyHaveAccountButton.centerX(inView: view)
        alreadyHaveAccountButton.anchor(bottom: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
    }
    func configureNotificationsObservers() {
        emailTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
        passwordTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
        fullnameTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
       usernameTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
        //phonenumberTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
    }
}
extension RegisterationController: FormViewModel {
    func updateForm() {
        signUpButton.backgroundColor = viewModel.buttonBackgroundColor
        signUpButton.setTitleColor(viewModel.buttonTitleColor, for: .normal)
        signUpButton.isEnabled = viewModel.formIsValid
    }
}

//MARK: - UIImagePickerViewDelegate
extension RegisterationController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        guard let selectedImage = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage else {return}
        profileImage = selectedImage
        plushButton.layer.cornerRadius = plushButton.frame.width / 2
        plushButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
        plushButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        plushButton.layer.borderWidth = 2
        plushButton.setImage(selectedImage.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

This is the Auth service view controller for authenticating the users for sign up and login. I have used GCP Documentation for this whole segment so please tell me if there is an issue here. I also don't receive any errors in my console. Like zero errors.

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseAuth
import Firebase

struct AuthCredentials{
    let email: String
    let username: String
    let password: String
    let profileImage: UIImage
    let fullname: String
   // let phoneNumber: String
}
struct AuthService {
    static func registerUser(withCredentials credentials: AuthCredentials, completion: @escaping(Error?) -> Void) {
        ImageUploader.uploadImage(image: credentials.profileImage) { imageUrl in
            Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: credentials.email, password: credentials.password) { (results, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("DEBUG: Failed to register user \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    return
                }
                
                guard let uid = results?.user.uid else { return }
                let data: [String: Any] = ["email": credentials.email,
                                           "fullname": credentials.fullname,
                                           "profileImageUrl": imageUrl,
                                           "uid": uid,
                                           "username": credentials.username]
                                           //"phoneNumber": credentials.phoneNumber]
                Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(uid).setData(data, completion: completion)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Image Uploader View controller for cloud storage

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseAuth
import Firebase

struct AuthCredentials{
    let email: String
    let username: String
    let password: String
    let profileImage: UIImage
    let fullname: String
   // let phoneNumber: String
}
struct AuthService {
    static func registerUser(withCredentials credentials: AuthCredentials, completion: @escaping(Error?) -> Void) {
        ImageUploader.uploadImage(image: credentials.profileImage) { imageUrl in
            Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: credentials.email, password: credentials.password) { (results, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("DEBUG: Failed to register user \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    return
                }
                
                guard let uid = results?.user.uid else { return }
                let data: [String: Any] = ["email": credentials.email,
                                           "fullname": credentials.fullname,
                                           "profileImageUrl": imageUrl,
                                           "uid": uid,
                                           "username": credentials.username]
                                           //"phoneNumber": credentials.phoneNumber]
                Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(uid).setData(data, completion: completion)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. When posting questions, please provide enough information so we understand the issue. Saying 'it doesn't work' is too vague. You can start by adding a breakpoint to your code and stepping though it line by line, examining your vars and code flow along the way. When you spot something that isn't right, include your findings and what line it was *in the question* then we can take a look. You can also sprinkle some print statements in your code to see what it's doing and better error handling; doing this `else { return }` will silently fail and you'll never know why.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).